# How do I make Sequel treat column as an integer?

Tags: ruby, sequel

`sequel` interprets `tinyint(1)` fields as a `boolean` type. While reasonable most of the time, is there a way to get to the real integer value?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 TINYINT(1));

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (0), (1), (2);

$ type 1.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'sequel'
require 'pp'
$DB = Sequel.connect(
    adapter: 'mysql2',
    database: 'd1',
    user: 'u1',
    password: '...',
)
pp $DB[:t1].all
$ ./1.rb
[{:f1=>false}, {:f1=>true}, {:f1=>true}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this might be what you need: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/MySQL.html

specifically, calling

```
Sequel::MySQL.convert_tinyint_to_bool = false
```

somewhere in your initialisation code.

Comment: Yep, `$DB.convert_tinyint_to_bool = false` in my case.